# Javascript MVC for a simple app does not work

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Reffering to my previous question (about simple pocket calculator), I try to rewrite it using MVC pattermn. I understand the basics of MVC but to implement it is pretty difficult for a beginner. so my html code is :

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SimpleCalculator.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/SC_Controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/SC_Model.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             new SC_Controller().init();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="display"><input type="text" readonly size="18" id="displayId"></div>
        <div class="keys">
            <p><input type="button" class="button black" value="7">
               <input type="button" class="button black" value="8">
               <input type="button" class="button black" value="9">
               <input type="button" class="button orange" value="/">
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" class="button black" value="4">
                <input type="button" class="button black" value="5">
                <input type="button" class="button black" value="6">
                <input type="button" class="button orange" value="*">
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" class="button black" value="1">
               <input type="button" class="button black" value="2">
               <input type="button" class="button black" value="3">
               <input type="button" class="button orange" value="-">
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" class="button black0" value="0">
               <input type="button" class="button black" value=".">
               <input type="button" class="button orange" value="+"></p>
            <p><input type="button" class="button greenc" value="C">
               <input type="button" class="button yelloweq" value="="></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my two JS filController.js are :

SC_Controller.js

```
var SC_Controller = function(scModel){
   var model = scModel || new SC_Model();
   var s = "";


   function clicked(){
       s += model.getValue();
       alert(s);
       model.setValue(s);
   }

   function init(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("button").onclick = clicked;
    }

    return {
        init : init;
        model : model
    };
};
```

and

SC_Model.js

```
var SC_Model = function(){

    function getValue(){
        return(document.getElementsByClassName('button').value);
    }

    function setValue(val){
        document.getElementById('displayId').value = val;
    }

    return{
        getValue : getValue,
        setvalue : setValue
    };
};
```

To implement a MVC pattern, I googled and found an example. I tried to adapt it to my calculator code, but launching the HTML, when I click a key the alert box in SC_Controller.js does not pop up. I can not understand why. Could you help me ?

Comment: Sorry : the line "and my two JS filController.js does not pop up, meaning that the ces are :" should be read "and my two js files are"

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByClassName("button")` returns a collection of nodes
(*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName*).

You need to iterate over them when applying the click handler as well as when requestion their `.value`.

For instance, the

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button").onclick = clicked;
```

should be

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
    buttons[i].onclick = clicked;
```